# Can't find Honeycomb switch ON/OFF control

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-button, android-controls

On the page 19 of this slides from Google I/O 2011: [Google I/O 2011](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/designing_and_implementing_android_uis_for_phones_and_tablets.pdf) , we can find several controls from the Honeycomb platform. On the bottom of the page there is a switch on/off control, but I'm not able to find it at all on the 3.0 Android Platform. What am I doing wrong? Whats the proper name of this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `Switch` widget only available in Ice Cream Sandwich (API 14):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

Comment: I tried this control already, but it doesn't looks like the one of the presentation at all. Its just a button that has one text inside, and if you click it, the text changes, but it doesn't look like a switch.

Comment: Please check the page 19 of the slide I posted. There is this toggle button, but on the middle-bottom of the slide, there is the switch.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see your mentioning of the specific page. I'll do some searching.

Comment: Sounds and looks like the `Switch` widget to me. Altough this is new for ICS, and i didn't try it yet, so I'm not sure. Have a look. Doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

Comment: Then why is that on the Google presentation of Honeycomb? I don't get it... But ok! Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: No idea - perhaps it was supposed to be in Honeycomb, but was postponed.

Comment: `Switch` is used internally in Honeycomb (e.g., airplane mode and WiFi toggles in the expanded system bar) but is only part of the SDK in ICS. If/when the ICS code ships, I suspect that it will be fairly simple to create a repackaged `Switch` that works on earlier versions of Android.